# Is there a way to set the DateTime for a thread/application with arbitrary value

Tags: c#, testing, datetime

I need this in few of my automation test cases. The major functionality is time dependent and this causes test cases to fail if I run them during the day time for which there's no record.

I know I have another but relatively tedious option of mocking the repository and generate the time dependent data at runtime, but – I just want to know whether I can do this in other way – by controling the DateTime for an application and/or thread such that DateTime.Now returns the value based on what I set somewhere at the start?

Is it really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeMock isolator [claims to be able to do this](http://blog.typemock.com/2009/05/mockingfaking-datetimenow-in-unit-tests.html). Personally, though, I would rather change my code to inject an `IClock` and use that. The production clock might use `DateTime.Now` (or `UtcNow`), but I can provide a mock simply and cleanly.

If that affects too many things, maybe a static implementation, so you can use `Current.Time` or something (where `Current` is your class), but which allows indirection / spoofing for tests. Indeed, that could be done using the above, simply with:

```
private static IClock clock = new DateTimeClock();
public static void SetClock(IClock clock) { Current.clock = clock; }
public static DateTime Time { get { return clock.Now; } }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, your solution is nice. It seems though there's no "legitimate" way to set DateTime.Now, so clock factory is a nice way to go.